# Alternative for javacv methods in opencv library

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Here is the thing, I want to change my code from using `javacv` methods to `opencv` methods. I have no idea which methods I should use instead of some methods in javacv. It would be so appreciated if some experienced guy can help me with this, the methods I want to change are:

```
 switch(nRec) {
        case 0: faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1,8,8,8,100);
                break;
        case 1: faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
                break;
        case 2: faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
                break;
        }
```

I also have unresolved reference to `MatVector` in:

```
    File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

    MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);
```

`cvLoadeImage()` and `IplImage` in:

```
IplImage img=null;
        String p = image.getAbsolutePath();
        img = cvLoadImage(p);
```

PS: I must mention that I have imported openCV library to my project and I import its classes to my code but I still have these unresolved issues. After I searched the web I figured out that `javacv` methods are incompatible with opencv library and I want to use alternative methods for them.

Comment: both apis are essentially incompatible. with the opencv wrappers , you will have to use Highgui.imread() and Core.Mat, no IplImages there (for the better). also, the bad news is - to get the facerecognition running, you will need a bit of jni support (the createXXXXFaceRecognizer methods are missing)

Comment: also, the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) .